# R updating dataframe elements given that a separate column element exists in another vector

Tags: r

I have a vector vec:

```
a<-c(4,2,9,2)
```

And a dataframe df:

```
   indx explore_ind
1     1        dark
2     2        dark
3     3        dark
4     4        dark
5     5        dark
6     6        dark
7     7        dark
8     8        dark
9     9        dark
10   10        dark
    
    df<-structure(list(indx = 1:10, explore_ind = c("dark", "dark", "dark", 
"dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to update any explore_ind from "dark" to "light" where indx exists in vec.

The result should be:

```
  indx explore_ind
1     1        dark
2     2        light
3     3        dark
4     4        light
5     5        dark
6     6        dark
7     7        dark
8     8        dark
9     9        light
10   10        dark
```

Comment: `df[df$indx %in% a,"explore_ind"]="light"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifelse` option:

```
df$explore_ind <- ifelse(df$indx %in% a, "light", "dark")
df
```

Output:

```
   indx explore_ind
1     1        dark
2     2       light
3     3        dark
4     4       light
5     5        dark
6     6        dark
7     7        dark
8     8        dark
9     9       light
10   10        dark
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R

The square brackets allows us to subset by index when we are subseting a vector, which is what we have when we use `$`  on a column name

```
df$explore_ind[a] <- "light"
```

If indx isn't sorted you can use

`df$explore_ind[df$indx %in% a] <- "light"`

as suggested by @user2974951

Comment: What if "indx" is not sorted?

Comment: We'll cross that bridge when we see it ;). Yeah u make a great point. I just made that assumption

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df<-structure(list(indx = 1:10, explore_ind = c("dark", "dark", "dark", 
                                                "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                        10L), class = "data.frame") %>% 
  as_tibble()

a<-c(4,2,9,2)

df %>%  
  mutate(explore_ind = case_when(indx %in% a ~ "light", 
                                 TRUE ~ explore_ind))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>     indx explore_ind
#>    <int> <chr>      
#>  1     1 dark       
#>  2     2 light      
#>  3     3 dark       
#>  4     4 light      
#>  5     5 dark       
#>  6     6 dark       
#>  7     7 dark       
#>  8     8 dark       
#>  9     9 light      
#> 10    10 dark
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>